# What does "significant rank correlation" mean in the context of Kendall Tau-B?

Tags: correlation, nonparametric, kendall-tau

I am trying to understand how to correctly interpret "significant rank correlation" in the context of Kendall Tau-B. What can I conclude if the correlation is 1? The relationship is monotonic?

Edit:
[Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.se/scholar?q=%22significant+rank+correlation%22+kendall+tau&btnG=&hl=sv&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=2012)

Comment: In which context did you find 'significant rank correlation'? Did you find it in a paper?

Comment: For example at [unistat.com](https://www.unistat.com/guide/correlation-coefficients/) at the bottom of 6.2.1.3. Kendall’s Rank Correlation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, **"significant rank correlation"** means that the value you obtained for your Kendall's $\tau_B$ is **significantly different from 0**. Indeed, the value you obtained for $\tau_B$ might be just due to chance because of small sample size, i.e. small number of objects. You might have to get familiar with [statistical hypothesis testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing).

In statistical hypothesis testing for correlation measures, you usually compute a $p$-value which is function of the *effect size* of the correlation and the *sample size*. When the $p$-value is low, you can reject the hypothesis of 0 correlation with some chosen level of confidence. An example about Kendall's $\tau_B$ in R is [here](http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/correlation/kendall-tau-b).

Comment: Null hypothesis is no correlation. If p is smaller than 0.05 (95% confidence interval) the hypothesis is rejected on this level which means there is correlation. Does $\tau_B$ show the level of monotonicity (strictly growing is +1 and strictly declining is -1) while the p value tells how often I would find $\tau_B$ within the confidence interval if I did the experiment many times?

Comment: Yes $\tau_B$ accounts for the level of monotonicity between your variables. A $p$-value shows how strongly you can reject the hypothesis of 0 correlation. However, be careful when you talk about reproducibility of results: http://www.nature.com/news/scientific-method-statistical-errors-1.14700

Comment: Would it be better to say that I am 95% certain that $\tau_B$ is in this interval?

Comment: That is also another different thing. A $p$-value is not the same as a confidence interval